# mysql update is updating all rows instead of one

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I am having an issue that I cant seem to figure out what is wrong. I am aware of SQL injection but considering the users I am not worried.

Ok so the issue I have is when i update. If i put `$update = "UPDATE robert SET req='$reqs' WHERE id='$x'";` it does nothing and if i put `$update = "UPDATE robert SET req='$reqs'";` it updates the entire column, which is not what i want. 
Here is the complete code:

```
<?php
                $i = 0;
                $x = 0;
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM robert";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo "<form action='rmcclanahan.php' method='post'>
                    <table><tr>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='date".$i."' value='".$row['date']."' size='8'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='req".$i."' value='".$row['req']."' size='6'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='po".$i."' value='".$row['po']."' size='6'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='requestor".$i."' value='".$row['requestor']."' size='6'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='line".$i."' value='".$row['line']."' size='5'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='description".$i."' value='".$row['description']."' size='12'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='price".$i."' value='".$row['price']."' size='12'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='supplier".$i."' value='".$row['supplier']."' size='6'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='eleven".$i."' value='".$row['eleven']."' size='12'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='carcap".$i."' value='".$row['carcap']."' size='12'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='carnum".$i."' value='".$row['carnum']."' size='6'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='engineering".$i."' value='".$row['engineering']."' size='12'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='costcenter".$i."' value='".$row['costcenter']."' size='6'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='accnum".$i."' value='".$row['accnum']."' size='5'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='recieved".$i."' value='".$row['recieved']."' size='6'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='recdate".$i."' value='".$row['recdate']."' size='8'></td>";
                    echo "<td><button type='submit' name='submit".$i."'>Edit</button></td>";
                    echo "</tr></table>
                    </form>";


                    $i++;
                    $x++;

                    }
                    if(isset($_POST['submit'.$i.''])){
                            $reqs = $_POST['req'.$i.''];
                            $update = "UPDATE robert SET req='$reqs' WHERE id='$x'";
                            $qry = mysqli_query($conn, $update);

                            }
```

Comment: MySQL cannot see your PHP code, much less run it. What counts is the actual generated SQL code.

Comment: The `if` statement is outside the while loop so `$i` and `$x` will always be 1 greater than the number of rows in the table. That seems like a problem.

Comment: I have moved this up into the while loop just above the incremented variables, which makes sense but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide the actual id in the WHERE clause, not some arbitrary number.

The query should be like this:

```
$update = "UPDATE robert SET req=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($update);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $reqs,$row['id']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Also note that you must use prepared statements to avoid errors and injections.